# Replace double quote with single quote using laravel select query

Tags: jquery, laravel

I am using laravel to get data from my database
where i required to get the instruction with single quote
Means wants to replace double quote with single quote wherever the double quote is used.
I am new to laravel, i know query structure of MySql and understanding laravel so any suggestion will be helpful for me.

**Edited**

An example of MySql Query is as below, I wants something like this in laravel

```
select replace(col_instruction,'"',"'") from mytable
```

Comment: Your query is working. what issue you are getting ?

Comment: This is sql query i wants this in Laravel format something like `$users = DB::table('users')->select(replace(col_instruction,'"',"'"))->get();` but unfortunately this is not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#selects), this should work:

```
$result = DB::table('mytable')->select(DB::raw('replace(col_instruction, \'"\',"\'")'))->get();
```

Comment: You forgot the ending round bracket for `(DB::raw(...))` but this is working for me. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Fixed, thanks. Please upvote, if you want to thank me. )